# Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, web, backend

I have started to learn back - end development on Python, specifically in Flask. But always meet new problems

Project Structure

```
 |
 |
  -- blog
 |     -- templates
 |      |
 |       -- *html files*
 |     -- __init__.py
 |     -- DataBase.py
 |     -- routes.py
 |     -- users.db
 |     -- user.sql
 |
  -- run.py
```

*Inside **run.py:***

```
from blog import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*Inside __***init __.py :**

```
from flask import Flask
from blog import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
```

*Inside **DataBase.py :***

```
import sqlite3


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, db, schema):
        self.db = db
        self.schema = schema

    # Connect
    def get_connection(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        return conn

    # Initialize
    def init_db(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
        with open(self.schema, 'r') as s:
            conn.executescript(s.read())

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    
    # Get All Data from database
    def getAllData(self):
        conn = self.get_connection()
        users = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM users""").fetchall()

        conn.close()
        return users
```

*Inside **routes.py :***

```
from blog import app
from DataBase import DataBase
from flask import render_template

data = DataBase('users.db', 'user.sql')


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
@app.route('/home', methods=["GET"])
def about():
    users = data.getAllData()
    return render_template('home.html', users=users)


@app.route('/team/<int:user_id>', methods=["GET"])
def members(user_id):
    if user_id == 1:
        return render_template('mirshod.html')

    elif user_id == 2:
        return "Hello World"


@app.route('/team', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def team():
    users = data.getAllData()
    return render_template('home.html', users=users)
```

Before re - structuring my project everything was well, but after re - structuring I am getting error when try to run my project

```
Try 'python -m flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'run', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\flaskMarket\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
File "D:\\fastApiProject\\flaskProject\\run.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from blog import app
File "D:\\fastApiProject\\flaskProject\\blog\__init_\_.py", line 2, in \<module\>
from blog import routes
File "D:\\fastApiProject\\flaskProject\\blog\\routes.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from blog import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'blog' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\\fastApiProject\\flaskProject\\blog\__init_\_.py)

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add ”urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Use https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/blueprints/ You may **never** import the APP somewhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

You didn't exactly ask a question, so I'll explain why you're getting this error at all. Think about it like this:

1. `run.py` is trying to import `app` from `blog`
2. While doing that, the `__init__.py` file tries to import `routes` from `blog`
3. Inside `routes.py`, it tries to import `app` from `blog`

... hence taking us back to step 2. Meaning that this would loop infinitely. Thankfully, Python realizes this and crashes immediately instead.

To fix this, you need to set up your imports in a way that `app` will already be loaded when it is imported, or set it up in a way that `app` is not recursively imported (like putting the `app` object directly in `routes.py`):

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
data = DataBase('users.db', 'user.sql')

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
@app.route('/home', methods=["GET"])
...
```